# select a href link as tab from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net

I've a asp.net page that is having few tabs using jquery tab and under some condition, i woul like to have 'Tab 2' selected when the page load instead of 'Tab 1' that is always default to selected.

```
<div id="tab-container" class="tab-container">
    <ul class='etabs'>
        <li class='tab'><a id="tab1" runat="server" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a id="tab2" runat="server" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a id="tab3" runat="server" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a id="tab4" runat="server" href="#tab4">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li class='tab'><a id="tab5" runat="server" href="#tab5">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running when this condition is met:

```
$('#tab2').click();
```

From code behind you can run this via `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: it doesn't works....Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "activateTab", "$('#tab2').click();", True)

Comment: Does this work in client-side code, e.g. if you place it in some button click?

Answer (score 0):

You can take couple of approaches,

**Option1:**
I would recommend use default Tab Setting as an attribute from the asp.net response.

You can set default tab == "Tab2" and emit the attribute as selected to your response.

**Option2:**

You can make a call on "$(document).ready()" and make the Tab2 default , not a good approach, the screen will flicker after the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the active property of jquery tabs as zero-based index of which tab you want to be shown on page load like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs({ active: 1 });
});
```

Check this example here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2MMaA/1/